# Different video attributes on mobile in HTML page

Tags: html, video, mobile

I have a very simple html page that hosts only a video. The `controls` attribute is absent and `autoplay` is present. This prevents the movie from playing on mobile (autoplay is banned and it cannot be started without controls).

```
<video class="center" width="1280" height="720" loop autoplay="autoplay" ondblclick="makeFullScreen(this)" >
```

Is there a way using either an attribute or some javascript to have different attribute for mobile and desktop, for example by using the `media` attribute and a restriction on the screen size? A PHP solution serving different pages would also be acceptable, but second best.

Answer (score 0):

there are loads of JavaScript functions out there to detect if the client device is mobile or desktop. You can choose any such function ([What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery))
afterwards you make a simple if stmnt (if the device is mobile add control attribute)
Alternatively as you mentioned you can detect this with php and make a similar if stmnt

Comment: I can do the if part, not sure how to go about "adding" the control attribute, could you demonstrate?

Comment: i did it with jquery. i believe this would be the code. (obliviously you would put this in an if statement  $('#elementId').attr('controls','on');